# how to push some of the required search results at the top(most relevant results)

Tags: sharepoint-search

My actual requirement is suppose i have 10 different products in my list from different vendors,some of the vendors are preferred by my organization, these products are viewed by my organization from different regions, so if my organization UK branch is viewing these products and "**Vendor A**" is preferred vendor for them then they should see products from "**Vendor A**" at top of the page.

similarly preferred vendors could change for different regions so they should see results from there preferred partners first followed by other results.

can this be achieved out-of-the-box in sharepoint server 2013 enterprise or we need to play with the ranking models?

Comment: Look in to Promoted results: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/02/01/how-query-rules-and-result-sources-can-be-used-to-customize-search-results.aspx

Comment: @RobertLindgren you beat me to it.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what Query Rules were designed for.

Query Rules allow you to promote certain results in SharePoint Search.

You will find Query Rules under Site Settings. These can be configured either at the Site Collection or Web level. Take a look at these as they will help you understand how to create your own.

A great example of this is in People Search. Usually, when you search for a person in your organisation under 'Everything' you will notice a block at the top of your results. Something like 'People name 'QueryHere''.

The query rule for this looks like this:

[image: Query Rule]

The process for these are as follows:

1. When I make a search against a Result Source (in this case the default Local SharePoint Results), SharePoint will match the query against a set of rules (Query Rules).
2. When the query matches a rule, it will carry out some Actions.

You have the following Actions available to you

- Add Promoted Results. This is basically what used to be called Best Bets in previous SharePoint. This adds a Static result at the top of your search results when the rule is fired.
- **Add Result Block. This will most likely fit your requirements.** This is what is fired when you see the 'People named 'etc'' when searching for people in your organisation. These Result Blocks can be pushed to the top of your search results (Promoted Result Block) or ranked as a whole amongst your entire result set (Ranked Result Block)
- You also have the option to change the ranking of results when your query rule is fired if you wish.

Addtional Links:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/02/01/how-query-rules-and-result-sources-can-be-used-to-customize-search-results.aspx

These videos also provide great coverage of Search: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn756397.aspx