# Breaking up SharePoint Search Results

Tags: search

Have a request of breaking up SharePoint Search results in two sections. For instance, if I search the word "Bike" they want one section of search results to display when "Bike" is in the title.

The second section would display when "Bike" is found within the document, and not the title.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 3):

You can use query rules and [Result Blocks](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34052.sharepoint-2013-create-custom-result-blocks-using-query-rules.aspx) for this purpose.  Check out z.rahui's [answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116467/how-to-push-some-of-the-required-search-results-at-the-topmost-relevant-results) to a similar question on SharePoint Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm getting close I think but having a hard time testing this and getting it to show up as a result. I'm currently under Site Settings > Edit Query Rule, and going through the Result Block:
Query Builder Settings:
Select a Query > Local SharePoint Results
Keyword Filter > Query from the search box
Query Text > {?Title:{SearchBoxQuery}}
Problem is when I cannot test it from here because I don't have a search box here to test with. If I change the property filter to manual and put in something like "Document Control" it seems like it's working but not showing up when I search from the site.

Answer (score 1):

The same way (or similar) as result blocks are [promoted results](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34049.sharepoint-2013-promoted-search-results.aspx)